# Помогут ли promise в Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise

Поможет ли использование обещаний в Node.js для тяжелых вычислений?
Например для сборки проектов на сервере.

Допустим, мне нужно взять некий набор данных из БД, объединить их, вычислить что-то и, в итоге, я получаю код, который будет выполняться довольно-таки долго - Node.js застопорится на моменте вычислений и заставит ждать все остальные задачи. В Node.js всё работает асинхронно кроме кода, ведь так?

Используя обещания, я смогу сделать код асинхронным: сделать обещание, которое сделает все вычисления параллельно и, при завершении всех операций, скажет, что можно идти дальше - создавать папку, например, и закидывать в неё все данные проекта.

Comment: Вы задали вопрос на который нужно ответить Да или Нет. Что сложно сделать не зная всех условий Вашей задачи. Попробуйте привести конкретный пример конкретной задачи и попросить объяснить как лучше решить эту задачу: через промисы или что-то еще. Думаю это повысит шансы на ответ. Ну и промисы это всего лишь инструмент. Иными словами вы спросили: Поможет ли молоток построить дом?))

Comment: @KirillErmolov, я понимаю что инструмент) Задача идёт в том что бы не допустить ступора node, выполнить операцию с большими вычислениями в фоне, дочерний процесс запустить или использовать promise?

Comment: какую базу данных и фреймворк ты используешь?

Comment: чистый  node, mongodb.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Мало знаю о вашем проекте, но допустим, что есть асинхронная функция `meeedlennnno()`, которая требует довольно много времени, скажем, тридцать секунд, вычислить что-то.

Теперь есть большая проблема: весь код выполняется в одном процессе, значит, если вызываете `meeedlennnno()`, начинает вычисление, и в то же время пользователь отправит запрос вашему серверу, ему придется ждать по крайнем мере тридцать секунд.

Это не зависит от использования обещаний. Обещания ничего волшебного не творят, обещания просто как [синтаскический сахар](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BA%D1%81%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9_%D1%81%D0%B0%D1%85%D0%B0%D1%80) для callback'ов. Функция выполняется асинхронно, но все таки в одном и том же процессе со всем остальным.

Такая проблема есть и в браузере и в Node.js. Как решить? В браузере используют Web Workers и в Node.js запустят [дочерние процессы](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html).

Comment: Добавлю еще что с помощью таких функций как `setImmediate` вы можете сделать вычисления в функции `meeedlennnno()` ассинхронными. Это не ускорит работу функции но и вычисление этой функции не приведет к блокировки процесса. И да вы можете прикрутить там промисы, чтобы не возиться с колбеками. Кстати вот [доклад](https://events.yandex.ru/lib/talks/1502/) тут спикер примерно на 55-ой минуте разбирает пример с вычислением n-ого числа последовательности фибоначи в *node.js*. Возможно это как раз то что вам нужно.